# Moving left one slot the leftmost 1-bit of an integer while other 1-bits remain unchanged?

Tags: bit-manipulation

For example: `000010011` will be turned into `000100011`.

Comment: add 2^(x+1)where x is the position (0 being the rightmost position)

Answer (score 0):

What about this (pseudocode):

```
x=Your Bit
y=10000000

While((x&y)==0)
{
    y=>>1
}
x+y
```

Only works if your bit is not 0

Answer (score 0):

C++, assuming signed int, O(n), where n is decided by the position of leftmost bit '1'

```
#include <climits> // INT_MIN
int moveLeftmostLeft(int n)
{
  if(n==0) return 0;
  int flag = INT_MIN; // 1000 0000 ... 0000
  while((flag&n)==0)
    flag=(unsigned)flag>>1;
  return n+flag;
}
```